# Finding the value of radio button checked in base page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web form with two radio buttons and a submit button on it. I am inheriting this web form from BasePage. On my baase page, I have the following method:

```
protected override void RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl,string eventArgument)
    {
        // here is the control that caused the postback
        var postBackControl = sourceControl;

        base.RaisePostBackEvent(sourceControl, eventArgument);
    }
```

when I click on any radio button and then submit button, I tried to inspect the value of postBackControl in debug mode, I get submit value in postbackcontrol. Below is the image:

[image]

Is their any way, I can find out which radio button has been clicked in this base page.

My radio buttons on the web form are like so:

```
                 <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbEng1"  runat="server" Text="English"  GroupName="lang"   />
                  <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbspan1"  runat="server" Text="Español"  GroupName="lang"  />
                  <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Submit_Click"   />
```

I tried to do Request.Form["rdbEng1"] in method RaisePostBackEvent, but the value is always null. The reason, I want to see which radio button is checked in the base class is because I want to set the language based on users selection.  I have this method in my base class called :

```
   protected  override void InitializeCulture()
        {
           //Set the Culture.
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(language);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(language);
         }
```

If I set the culture in the button submit event of the web form then it does not convert all the lines on my page to another language, but if I set the language in my base class then all the lines on my web page are converted to another language.This is the line that is not getting converted to a different language:

```
<asp:RadioButton  ID="rdbtest" AutoPostBack="true"  runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:Resource1, Informational %>"
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can write event handler for button click event and get the radio button values there

Comment: Then it will be on the same web form. I want the value of the radio button in the base page. when the user clicks on the submit button on web form, I go to the base page. On this Base Page, I want to know which radio button has been clicked.

Comment: I am inheriting the web form from the base page. I dont even have to write eventHandler, I can get the value on the web form easily on the submit_clcik event, but I need this value on the base page.

Comment: Why you want to access child class controls in parent class? What's the use case you see trying to solve? Can you explain bit more?

Comment: I modified my question above. Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: I can also provide which lines are not getting converted to different language if you need that information.

Answer (score 0):

Have your tried storing the value in a Session variable then look up the session variable from wherever you need it? The Session variable should live on all pages in the app.

Comment: I can store the value in session variable if I know which radio button has been checked, I caanot find that unless i can access the radio button value in the base page

Comment: not sure what you are doing but can you pass the control into the method as a parm? e.g RadioButton rd1, RadioButton rd2)

Answer (score 0):

Just use properties in the base-page:

base page:

```
protected string Language 
{
    get { return (string)this.ViewState["Language"]; }
    set { this.ViewState["Language"] = value; }
}
```

ChildPage:

```
protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    if (rdbEng1.Checked) 
        this.Language = "en-US";
    else if (rdbspan1.Checked)
        this.Language = "es-ES";
    ...
}
```